# Uwamp Mysql Server from CD stops running after 5 seconds

Tags: mysql, webserver, wamp, cddvd, uwamp

I'm Creating a new version of an old Flash application, this application will be written with HTML 5, one of the Requests is that the web application is runable from a CD/DVD.

Using UwAmp I've been able to start the program from the CD/DVD and Apache runs perfectly but Mysql stops after 5 seconds.

I have a feeling I need to change some settings to keep it running as the web application and the data in the MySQL database will be non editable(on CD/DVD) but it needs to be able to select items from the database.

all the steps i did till this point were; 
-> DL UwAmp
-> start and test if everything works
-> Burn on CD/DVD (non-editable) (same as with normal Burns of programs)(Program does NOT work)
-> Burn on CD/DVD (Editable) (like it's a flash drive) (Program works MySQL stops after 5 seconds)

I can't find anything really usefull on this subject for UwAmp on the internet thusfar. Anyone with knowledge on this subject that can tell me if i'm doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL need a write Access on the current storage.

So you can run it on a USB key but you can't from a CD.